# Origin of Double Integral Formulas for Volumes from Corral's Vector Calculus $\iint 1 - f(x,y)da$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, change-of-variable

Dear all I've been studying with Michael Corral's Vector Calculus book and in the Change of Variables part whenever he has a two variable function z = f(x,y) and we want to compute the volume of under the surface with z bound from 0 to 1.
He uses the integral $\iint_R(1-z)dA$.
I find the rest fairly intuitive but I've not been able to figure out why he starts with $1-z$ everytime. I do not think it's explained earlier. (I've read it multiple times, but to be fair I have a reading disability).

Could someone explain this to me?

Thank you very much!

I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious here. Apologies in advance!

Comment: It depends on the equation, say cone or paraboloid along $z-$ axis with vertex at the origin. Can you give an example?

Comment: @MathLover The two examples he shows are exactly a paraboloid and a cone.
How did you know?

Comment: because in both of these, if you take a strip along $z-$axis, it goes from $z$ to $1$ and not $0$ to $z$. Let me know if you can visualize or I can add a diagram to explain.

Comment: @MathLover Let me try for a bit. When you mean from z to 1. 1 refers to which axis? Thanks so much!!

Comment: Along $z$ axis. Say $z = x^2+y^2$ is your equation. Then if you take a circle at height $z$, the integration should go from $z$ to $1$ where you can represent $z$ as $x^2+y^2$.

Comment: @MathLover So like the disk method ? I still don't see where the $1-z$ comes from then. Apologies!

Comment: No that is the difference. If you were using disc method, you could just write $\int_0^1 \pi z \ dz $ (as $r^2 = x^2 + y^2 = z$). Here you are taking a strip along $z$ axis and rotating it around $z-$ axis.

Comment: @MathLover thanks! it took a while, but I think I got it now. I was thinking of the wrong "strip" because of the diagram in the book.
So can I think of $1-z$ as the height of the circle?
Thank's a lot!

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: @MathLover Thank you very much, you helped me out a lot!